# Not sure why React can't render <DIV>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

After researching this issue around the clocks, I am not sure it doesn't allow to work with `ReactDOM.render`, I get error message regarding `<DIV>` with webpack + babel which couldn't understand JSX syntax.

Package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = function() {
  return <div>Hello React! </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Chrome Console (error)

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./src/index.js"
```

^Instead simple error message, is there tools to show full messages in exact issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's s folders structure.

[image]

Comment: what does your directory structure look like?

Comment: Yep seems related to your architecture and web pack config, not a React issue

Comment: By the way, your bundle.js is after the `</body>` tag. I think you should move it inside the body  tag. Just after the DIV container.

Comment: Maybe you have ./src/index.jsx or you have typo in filenames? It's hard to say without the folder structure...

Comment: Please see screenshot above, I added it. @rossipedia

Comment: Yes, I did try that, still not working @TheLazyChap

Comment: I couldn't find my typo in the name of the file, see above @DmitryYaremenko

Comment: This error shows in browser after launching webpack-dev-server or it shows after bundle.js generating fail?

Comment: Need to see bundle.js, at some point it throws an error about "index.js"

Comment: Try remove content in index.js and replace by console.log('test')

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko - after launching webpack-dev-server

Comment: I replaced the content to add `console.log("test")`, it does show the word "test" in console, no error.

Comment: Maybe you trying to import "./src/index.js" in one of the components ?

Comment: Dang, where could I find **bundle.js** file? in node_modules?

Comment: @thunderRX5 It should be in the root folder after "webpack" launch.

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko - it worked finally now.  Just weird!  The first I tried last week was working with bundle.js like above but this second time went something wrong.  So I add new file **.babelrc** and add `{  "presets": ["es2015", "react"] }`.  That solved it.  :)

Comment: I re-install to double check - `npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev` and `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`

Answer (score 1):

A great way to understand those error messages is to look at your terminal to check the npm start process.

Scroll up and you will find there a more detailed, nicely formatted error message with the exact file and line where the problem in your code is.

I found this error to occur as a result of various syntax errors/typos.